# corporate action data

Tags: historical-data

Can someone recommend a good source for corporate action data?  I need at the very least: ticker changes, dividends, splits, acquisitions and delistings.  I historically used Bloomberg Back Office and am looking for a suitable replacement that is within a small team's budget besides just scraping a bloomberg terminal.

Edit:  More generally where are the major places getting their data?  Are they parsing each companies websites or some some sec filings that I am missing?  Is it from DTCC?

Comment: [NYSE](http://www.nyxdata.com/Data-Products/NYSE-Corporate-Actions) and [NASDAQ](http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/Trader.aspx?id=DailyListPD) both maintain master lists of corporate actions.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am not sure how I missed that.

Comment: This is a site for professional quants, and in accordance to the criteria for what is on-topic, questions asking for sources of data are discouraged.

Comment: I'll bite.  why are questions on quality of data off-topic?  (apparently, calendar data is on topic and basic NPV questions are.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on your budget of course, but:

- Mergent offers a [great service](http://www.mergent.com/mergent-solutions/corporate-actions-equity-pricing), expensive though.
- Six Financial Information offers good [Corporate Actions service](http://www.six-financial-information.com/en/home/global-data-services/corporate-actions.html). (Personally, I would go with this one)
- [Morning Star](http://corporate.morningstar.com/us/documents/MethodologyDocuments/FactSheets/MorningstarPrice&CorporateActionsFactSheet.pdf)
- [Interactive Data](http://www.interactivedata.com/index.php/productsandservices/content/id/Corporate+Actions) (very hard company to deal with, their legal would waste a lot of your time, but may still worth to get a quote)

Also, consider how much IT resources you have for accurately getting, parsing, processing and storing these data.

Answer (score -2):

Try Markit.com/RED a very reliable and accurate source

Comment: What is that a URL or the name of a product? Please make sure your answer are elaborate enough.

Comment: Try http://www.markit.com/Product/Corporate-Actions