# Is there a straightforward way to get a "family tree" for a stock?

Tags: equities, programming, market-data

I would like to find a way to generate what might be called a "family tree" for a stock.  Given a stock symbol and a future date, I'd like a graph (either literally or represented in list or other format) that shows stock splits, spinoffs, and mergers up to the present date or perhaps just to another specified date.

I'd also like to go backwards: given a stock symbol and a past date, I'd like a family tree that shows its ancestors from today (or perhaps a predefined date) back to the date I specify.

Does something like that exist?  I tend to work in R a lot, so that would be nice, although I'm also open to Web sites that might offer such a service, preferably for free.

Comment: It is quite a difficult project, especially if you want to go back many years. The tickers are not unique over the entire history and a ticker used today may even have been used by another unrelated company that now no longer exists.

Comment: Sometimes when 2 companies merge the surviving company uses the ticker of the first company but the name of the second company (or the name changes to something else). How would you handle that? It is a big mess.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have a hard time finding a tool that visualizes it for you. However, [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8472/corporate-action-data) question covers sources of the raw data on corporate actions needed to create such a tool yourself.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll leave this open for a bit more,  in case anyone turns up a more complete answer, but you and noob2 have largely persuaded me that this doesn't exist except possibly inside a few companies.